# How to color date columns in Grafana table

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I have several Raspberry Pis which are sending data to an influxDB instance. To ensure that the Raspberry Pis are working, I want to display the timestamp of the last message in a Grafana table. This work using the following metric:

```
SELECT "timestamp" FROM "monitoring-data" WHERE "host" =~ /^$host$/ AND $timeFilter GROUP BY "host"
```

having Format as "Time series" and ALIAS BY "$tag_host"

In option, I've set the table to transform to "Time series aggregations" and the Columns to "Current", since I want the most recent timestamp.

Now, I want to colour the fields having a timestamp older than 1 hour in red. But I don't get this option in the Columns Styles tab.

Any idea how I could do this? As a workaround, I could also calculate the time difference between now and the timestamp and then handle the columns as a Number type. But I can't figure out a query to do this.